# I need to find a string from a subset of columns in a file, not from the whole file

Tags: linux, shell, grep

I am using LINUX, and I would like to achieve this using the shell.

I want to extract the string "db2" from the field **in bold**, this corresponds to the "tags" field, this field is delimited by /tab, and I can't use fixed positions because it's of variable size.

**The actual file extract is:** presented 2 records, start with the time stamp.

[Jeff Y: formatted data]

```
create_ts   id  tags    title   body    answers

2011-01-03T20:52:52.880 5   **nosql^&^rdbms^&^database-recommendation** what are the differences between nosql and a traditional rdbms  what are the differences between nosql and a traditional rdbms   over the last few months  nosql has been frequently mentioned in the technical news  what are its most significant features relative to a traditional rdbms  at what level  physical  logical  do the differences occur   where are the best places to use nosql  why      nosql is a kind of database that doesn t have a fixed schema like a traditional rdbms does   with the nosql databases the schema is defined by the developer at run time   they don t write normal sql statements against the database  but instead use an 
2011-01-04T14:26:06.730 162 sql^&^explain-plan^&^db2    what does hsjoin mean in an explain plan    i have the following explain plan results from a query on my db2 database   0 select statement   estimated costs    5 928e 02  timerons           1 return            2 hsjoin                3  o  fetch ltbp                    4 ixscan ltbp m  key columns   0                5  i  fetch ltbk                    6 ixscan ltbk v  key columns   0   what does the hsjoin on line 2 mean    it s a hash join  
2011-01-07T16:44:52.210 394 **database-recommendation^&^feature comparison^&^permissions**  which database engines will allow me to grant revoke on a specific column   if i have a table with a single column of sensitive data  and i want to grant broad use of the table without exposing that one column  i know that i can create a view that gives them access to all the non sensitive columns  however  postgresql allows you to grant column level permissions in the form of  grant select  col1     coln  on table to role    are there other engines which provide this capability     sql server 2000  2005  2008 has this capability  grant   all   privileges              permission     column       n             n            on   class      securable   to
```

Comment: "but this is not efficient" -- meaning it's not robust or it's too slow?  Some problems are better suited for a richer language than just shell scripts.

Comment: You need to show us **actual** data not meaningless placeholders if you want any kind of meaningful, robust, accurate help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your sample data is not showing tab delimitation, but assuming all fields are in fact tab-delimited:

Using awk, you need to split the 3rd field on the tag delimiter and look for your tag in the result:

```
awk -F"\t" '{split($3,a,/\^&\^/);for(t in a)if(a[t]=="db2"){print;next}}'
```

Comment: Thanks very very much Jeff!, it's so good to have access to experts like you here!...

Answer (score 0):

`awk` to the rescue!
if you don't have markers to delimit the sections based on char count you can restrict the pattern match.

```
$ awk 'substr($0,start,length)~/pattern/' file
```

For example if the interested section starts at 14 and 9 chars long, search for pattern abc.

```
$ awk 'substr($0,14,9)~/abc/' file
```

If the data is delimited, say with tabs and you want your search to be restricted to say field 2, you can do this

```
$ awk -F'\t' '$2~/abc/' file
```

Of course these are just wild guesses until you have a concrete example to demonstrate the real problem and verify the scripts.

Comment: thanks for the response, I think I need to provide more information, in fact the string I want to look for is "db2" in the "tags" field, all the fields are delimited by /tab, I can't use fixed position as this field is variable, the actual data is above..

Comment: can you post a realistic input?  All I see is `x` and `*`.  Are the fields identical in each row?